# Creating a docker instance on connection to a WiFi network

Tags: docker

Is it possible to spin up a docker instance on connection to a WiFi network? 
I am looking to create sandbox environment on connection to a network and figured docker was the most suitable technology to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a native Linux install, WiFi is just another NIC to the kernel. Docker will bridge connections to this NIC without issue.

With Docker for Windows and Docker for Mac, the embedded Linux VM may need to be restarted to pickup networking changes if you change your networking environment (new DNS server, etc).